# Handling HTTP::ConnectionError with Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, savon

I am working with a rails 5 application and using `Savon` (2.12.1) for making XML request. Lately I am observing `HTTP::ConnectionError: couldn't read response headers` while making the request via `Savon`. Ideally I was expecting rescuing `Savon::Error` will handle all network related issues like `open_timeout` and `read_timeout`.

My Savon implementation looks like below

```
options = {
  wsdl:                    wsdl_url,
  endpoint:                wsdl_url + "/Secure/",
  logger:                  ::Logger.new("log/my_soap.log"),
  log:                     true,
  log_level:               :debug,
  pretty_print_xml:        false,
  convert_request_keys_to: :none,
  use_wsa_headers:         true,
  soap_version:            2,
  element_form_default:    :qualified,
  open_timeout:            50,
  read_timeout:            50
}
savon_client = Savon.client(options)

begin
  response = savon_client.call(method, message: args, headers: { 'content-type' => 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="' + savon_client.wsdl.soap_action(method) + '"' })
rescue Savon::Error => error
  # log and report errors
end
```

Do I need to rescue `HTTP::ConnectionError` additionally? And I am little confused with the error message `couldn't read response headers`, does this means request reached the 3rd party service or it failed to establish a connection?

Comment: This is likely a connection timeout.  You should  rescue `HTTP::Error` and see what's going on.